# Binance userDataStream sometimes does not work

Tags: c#, api, websocket, binance

I have a problem with [user_data](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/user-data-stream.md) subscription by [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#websocket-client). I have no any errors, but sometimes I have no data from server. I send listenKey and have empty response (no errors), but when I send order, I have no any callbacks from user_data.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I used wrong web socket component. I used [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/websocket-sharp.clone/) (websocket-sharp.clone). And when I changed it to WebSocketSharp, it works all this time.

Comment: Need to Share (with describe) your solving experience which will help everyone